# How to pass parameters to an ICommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I defined an ICommand-Class ReadPersons which reads all person objects from the database with a particular where-clause.

The command is being executed trough pressing a button and the where-clause is being insert in a textbox.

Question: How can i pass the text from the textbox to the Execute-Command?

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
    <Button Command="{Binding ReadPersons}">Read persons</Button>
    <TextBox Name="textBoxWhereClause" />
```

**ReadPersons.cs:**

```
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // Read all persons with my where-clause
        string whereClause = ??? //todo
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
<Button Command="{Binding ReadPersons}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBoxWhereClause}">
           Read persons</Button>
```

Comment: What will be write in its ICommand method to catch the parameter value ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button Command="{Binding ReadPersons}" CommandParameter="{Binding SomeProperty}" Content="Read Persons"/>
```